# Select only the values above "X"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a pivot table displaying the purchases over a year.

```
_____________________________________________
| CUSTOMER ID |    1    |    2    |    3    | ...
|___________________________________________|
|12345        |   200   |    -    |   100   | ...
|___________________________________________|
|45678        |   500   |   500   |   500   | ...
|___________________________________________|
|45678        |    10   |   500   |   50    | ...
|___________________________________________|
   ....           ....       ...      ...
```

Now I need to filter this table to show only the values that are above 150, while keeping everything else.

```
Desired Result
_____________________________________________
| CUSTOMER ID |    1    |    2    |    3    | ...
|___________________________________________|
|12345        |   200   |    -    |    -    | ...
|___________________________________________|
|45678        |   500   |   500   |   500   | ...
|___________________________________________|
|45678        |     -   |   500   |    -    | ...
|___________________________________________|
   ....           ....       ...      ...
```

I'm doing this on LiveSQL oracle and I'm going around on this problem for hours now, I can't seem to put a "WHERE" clause because it's either "OR" or "AND", which includes the whole entry or not. "HAVING" doesn't seem to work. Itried it everywhere I could remember, but after the IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12) it tells me that it's missing a right parenthesis (ORA-00907).

My code to get where I'm at:

```
SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT CUST_ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME_ID) AS "YEAR", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME_ID) AS "MONTH", AMOUNT_SOLD AS SPENT
            FROM SH.SALES
            )
    PIVOT(SUM(SPENT) FOR MONTH
                IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
                )
        ORDER BY CUST_ID
```

Does anyone know how i can solve this?

Comment: You are pulling year and month, but are only aggregating by month, is that by design or you're just dealing with a specific year?

Comment: can you share the sample data set, preferably within a fiddle ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan The dataset is publicly available on https://livesql.oracle.com/ under the schema HS. I'll be applying this on other data later but for now i'm just solving the problem.

Comment: @Isildur I just thought it wasn't important to display it in the ascii table i drew here, but yeah. i want to have one entry per year/ per customer_id

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 SELECT CUST_ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME_ID) AS "YEAR", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME_ID) AS "MONTH", AMOUNT_SOLD AS SPENT
 FROM SH.SALES
```

To

```
 SELECT CUST_ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME_ID) AS "YEAR", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME_ID) AS "MONTH", SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) AS SPENT
 FROM SH.SALES
 GROUP BY CUST_ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME_ID), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME_ID) 
 HAVING SUM(AMOUNT_SOLD) > 150
```

i.e. take all the customer's purchases that month, sum them up, and if they are less than (or equal to) 150, exclude them from the resultset. It means your pivot is now only pivoting/summing a single value rather than N values but it's the overall same effect (i.e. the SUM is done earlier, when preparing the data to be pivited, rather than summing during pivot)

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
CUSTOMER_ID, 
case when "1">150 then "1" end as "1",
case when "2">150 then "2" end as "2",
case when "3">150 then "3" end as "3",
```

instead of `*`

Comment: This also works! THANKS! The only minor detail is that it will show customer_ID's that don't have any value above 150.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this and what result you are expecting ?

```
select * from (
SELECT * FROM
            (SELECT CUST_ID, EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIME_ID) AS "YEAR", EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIME_ID) AS "MONTH", AMOUNT_SOLD AS SPENT
            FROM SH.SALES
            )
    PIVOT(SUM(SPENT) FOR MONTH
                IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
                )
        ORDER BY CUST_ID) where "1" > 150 and "2" > 150 and "3" > 150 and "4" > 150 and "5" > 150 and "6" > 150 and "7" >150 and "8" > 150 and "9" > 150 and "10" > 150
        and "11" > 150 and "12" > 150;
```

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't tried this but I think it's very similar to the solution from @Sayan Malakshinov, which I think it's a bit more readable.